# Json formatted string to list

Tags: c#, json, string, list

I have a string like this:

```
{"label":{"en":"Africa","de":"Afrika"},"description":{"en":"continent","de":"irdischer Kontinent"}}
```

Is possible convert to list like:

```
"label" - "en":"Africa","de":"Afrika"
"description" - "en":"continent","de":"irdischer Kontinent"
```

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for a JSON parser.

Comment: Just curious, why you do this?

Comment: that's a JSON string ,  just use a JSON parser

Comment: answer: yes it's possible

Comment: I must parsing a big dump of wikidata for some statistical analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, it looks like you're trying to process a JSON document. I recommend [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for this.

However, you *can* manipulate your string by itself if the transformation is very simple and you don't expect much variation in your input. One easy way would be to do something like this:

```
var result = input.Replace(":{", " - ")
                  .Replace("},", Environment.NewLine)
                  .Replace("{", string.Empty)
                  .Replace("}", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Maybe change "\n" to Environment.NewLine

Comment: Json.net is perfect. Thanks